# How change the FontName of Greek Letters at MATLAB TeX text?

Tags: matlab, fonts, non-ascii-characters, tex

How change the font type of Greek Letters at MATLAB TeX text? The 'FontName' does not work.

I try this code:

```
text(0.5, 0.7,'\it\Omega \phi A b','FontName','Times New Roman','FontSize',50);

text(0, 0.7,'\rm\Omega \phi A b','FontName','Times New Roman','FontSize',50);

text(0.5, 0.3,'\it\Omega \phi A b','FontName','Arial','FontSize',50);

text(0, 0.3,'\rm\Omega \phi A b','FontName','Arial','FontSize',50);
```

and this:

```
text(0.5, 0.7,'\fontname{Times New Roman}\it\Omega \phi A b','FontSize',50);

text(0, 0.7,'\fontname{Times New Roman}\rm\Omega \phi A b','FontSize',50);

text(0.5, 0.3,'\fontname{Arial}\it\Omega \phi A b','FontSize',50);

text(0, 0.3,'\fontname{Arial}\rm\Omega \phi A b','FontSize',50);
```

[At the MATLAB 2012a this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoRjr.png)

[At the MATLAB 2015b this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LREkI.png)

The font type of Greek Letters does not depend on the 'FontName'. But the font type of Greek Letters depends on the MATLAB version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to find a solution but unfortunately i'm having no good results. This is what i tried additionally *(cannot post in the comments since it is too long)*:

```
text(0.5, 0.7,'$\fontfamily{times} \it\Omega \phi A b$','interpreter','latex');
text(0.5, 0.7,'$\setmainfont{times} \it\Omega \phi A b$','interpreter','latex');

text(0.5, 0.3,'\fontname{GFS Artemisia}\it\Omega \phi A b','FontSize',50);
```

This one is the closest i got:

```
text(0.5, 0.7,'$\textsf{GFSArtemisia} \it\Omega \phi A b$','interpreter','latex');
```

It gives you a warning (**Font cmss10 is not supported.** To be clear i'm on matlab R2022a) that led me into a rabbit hole with most probably no end:

https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/412684-how-do-i-add-latex-fonts-in-matlab

Comment: Thank you, this almost resolves the issue.